# ¿Porqué solo lee primera línea de readobject?

Tags: java, java-stream

tengo 3 clases, una llamada Mueble que implementa la serialización, otra Utilidades que tiene los métodos para visualizarMensaje, leerTeclado, etc.. y finalmente la appGestionMuebles la cual crea la aplicación que permite añadir muebles. Cuando pruebo a añadir muebles funciona perfectamente, es más si visualizo el archivo MUEBLES1.DAT puedo ver como si se ha añadido, pero al imprimir con readObject, solo me visualiza el primero que añadí, ¿cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo? Gracias.

```
private static void listarMuebles() {

try (ObjectInputStream fichMueble = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("MUEBLES1.DAT")));){
    Mueble m ;
    Utilidades.visualizarMensaje(String.format("%10s", "ID MUEBLE") + String.format("%10s", "NOMBRE")
            + String.format("%10s", "TIPO") + String.format("%18s", "PRECIO UNITARIO")
            + String.format("%20s", "UNID. ALMACEN") + String.format("%10s", "TOTAL"));

    Utilidades.visualizarMensaje(String.format("%10s", "=========") + String.format("%10s", "======")
            + String.format("%10s", "====") + String.format("%18s", "===============")
            + String.format("%20s", "=============") + String.format("%10s", "====="));
    int i=0;
    while (true) {
        m = (Mueble) fichMueble.readObject();
        String tipoMueble = "";
        switch (m.getTipoMueble()) {
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                tipoMueble = "HOGAR";
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                tipoMueble = "DESPACHO";
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                tipoMueble = "COLEGIOS";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        
        }

        Utilidades.visualizarMensaje(String.format("%10s", m.getIdMueble())
                + String.format("%10s", m.getDescripMueble()) + String.format("%10s", tipoMueble)
                + String.format("%18s", m.getPrecioUnario()) + String.format("%20s", m.getUnidadesMinimas())
                + String.format("%10s", m.getUnidadesAlmacen()));
       
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Fin del fichero");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Puedes verificar que no te esté dando otra excepción que no esté siendo capturada en tu try/catch? Por ejemplo, puede darse alguna excepción que herede de IOException que no sea el fin de fichero. Puedes comprobar esto añadiendo trazas en tus catchs. Añadir el código completo para poder replicar el ejemplo también ayudaría.

Comment: ¿cómo añado el código completo, si son  3 clases distintas? Ayer recibía esta excepción: StreamCorruptedException, lo que hice para "solucionarlo" fue renombrar MUEBLES.DAT a MUEBLES1.DAT, aunque no entiendo el porqué de esa excepción...

Comment: @ordago He subido en Github los 3 ficheros class que crean la aplicación: https://github.com/Adrimofe/PracticaJava No sé si eso es suficiente

Comment: @ordago tras depurar el código como dijiste en la IOException visualizo que se produce otra excepción llamada StreamCorruptedException #641. Voy a buscar sobre esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución la encontré en la siguiente URL:
https://www.discoduroderoer.es/serializacion-de-objetos-en-java/
Dice textualmente:
¿Porque? La respuesta es que cuando escribimos un objeto en un fichero binario ObjectOutputStream crea una cabecera al principio y cuando cerramos el fichero y volvemos a añadir un objeto crea de nuevo una cabecera, haciendo que la información a partir de esta no pueda ser leída.
Para conseguir que no cree esta cabecera debemos crear una versión de la clase ObjectOutputStream, sobrescribiendo el método que crea esta cabecera.